# Get index in matrix using coordinates from linspace

Tags: numpy

I have a matrix *m* defined by two linspaces *x* and *y*:

```py
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100).reshape(1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100).reshape(100, 1)

m = x + 1j * y

# > m.shape
# (100, 100)
```

What if I want to set a value to a point at coordinates defined in the given linspace, not the array index?

For example, I would want to write something like this:

```py
m[-0.5, 0.123] = val
```

Is there an elegant way in numpy to convert from a coordinate system to the closest index in the array?

Comment: What do the coordinates refer to? The original x and y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible takes. You could use `np.searchsorted` to find an index based on value provided `x` and `y` are increasing. If `x` and `y` are evenly spaced (as in your example of `linspace`), then you can approximate the index of value `val` by `(val - (-1) / (1 - (-1)) * 100` in O(1) time.

```
import numpy as np

z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
m = z[None,:] + 1j * z[:,None]
# using searchsorted
f = lambda v: np.searchsorted(z, v)
# approximate the index using the fact that numbers in z are evenly spaced
g = lambda v: int((v - z[0]) / (z[-1] - z[0]) * z.shape[0])

print(m[f(0.5), f(0.123)])
# (0.1313131313131315+0.5151515151515154j)
print(m[g(0.5), g(0.123)])
# (0.1313131313131315+0.5151515151515154j)
```

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a built-in routine for that.